# insert checkbox in the cell content of a flextable object for word with rmarkdown

Tags: r, flextable

I am using RMarkdown and Shiny to generate a report template (in word format) which includes many tables with checkbox in their cell contents. I used the "flextable" package to create the tables. However, I am unable to insert the checkbox in tables. Any ideas on how to do this? For example, how should I make the "checkbox" actually show a checkbox in the final table?

```
x <- structure(list(col1 = c("test1", rep("1", 4), checkbox), col2 = c("test2", rep("", 5)), col3 = c("test3", rep("", 5)), col4 = c("test4", rep("", 5))), .Names = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), class = c("data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 6L))

MyFTable  <- flextable(x, col_keys = c("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"))
```

I tried to set

```
checkbox <- '<label><input type = "checkbox"> </label>'
```

but it didn't work.

For more clarity, please see the following pictures. Basically, I want something like this and the users of the template can check the checkbox in front of a certain item. For example, there are two items "Adequate" and "Inadequate" in the content of the cell at the right side of "Formulation". If a user of the report decides that "Adequate" is the right one, he can simply click the checkbox in front of "Adequate". 
[An image of the desired format of the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk7tn.jpg)

Comment: Do you want checkboxes that can be "clicked" or checkboxes as images would be OK?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, David. I want checkboxes that can be clicked.

Comment: OK, I am afraid that's not possible with flextable. flextable do not support raw html injection and I am not sure checkboxes are existing in Word.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so much for your reply!  Thank you also for developing this package. It is great!

Comment: I think checkboxes exist in Word though.

Comment: I am willing to have a look if you have a Word example. All I saw was *faking* checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a word file that has the checkboxes that I am talking about. However, I am not sure how to upload it (or email to you?)

Comment: thx. use the mail address in the DESCRIPTION file of officer.

Comment: Sent. Thank you so much, David. Please let me know if not receiving it.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but as I had a similar issue I will share the solution. The trick is to use the slip_in_xml function from officer library.

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)

my_doc <- read_docx()

my_doc <-  my_doc %>% 
  body_add_par('Heading 1', style = "heading 1") %>% 
  body_add_par(" ", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
  slip_in_xml(paste0('<w:sdt>
                       <w:sdtPr>
                       <w:id w:val="-990252438"/>
                       <w14:checkbox>
                       <w14:checked w14:val="0"/>
                       <w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
                       <w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
                       </w14:checkbox>
                       </w:sdtPr>
                       <w:sdtContent>
                       <w:r>
                       <w:rPr>
                       <w:rFonts w:ascii="MS Gothic" w:eastAsia="MS Gothic" w:hAnsi="MS Gothic" w:hint="eastAsia"/>
                       </w:rPr>
                       <w:t>☐</w:t>
                       </w:r>
                       </w:sdtContent>
                       </w:sdt>'), pos = 'after') %>%
  slip_in_text("pass", style = "strong") %>%
  slip_in_xml(paste0('<w:sdt>
                       <w:sdtPr>
                       <w:id w:val="-990252438"/>
                       <w14:checkbox>
                       <w14:checked w14:val="0"/>
                       <w14:checkedState w14:val="2612" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
                       <w14:uncheckedState w14:val="2610" w14:font="MS Gothic"/>
                       </w14:checkbox>
                       </w:sdtPr>
                       <w:sdtContent>
                       <w:r>
                       <w:rPr>
                       <w:rFonts w:ascii="MS Gothic" w:eastAsia="MS Gothic" w:hAnsi="MS Gothic" w:hint="eastAsia"/>
                       </w:rPr>
                       <w:t>☐</w:t>
                       </w:r>
                       </w:sdtContent>
                       </w:sdt>'), pos = 'after') %>%
  slip_in_text("fail", style = "strong") %>%
  body_add_par(" ", style = "Normal") %>% # blank paragraph
  slip_in_text("comment", style = "strong")

print(my_doc, target = "MVP.docx")
```

To get the xml code you can just create a word file, unzip it and extract needed xml. Two links which helped me: [An Informal Introduction to DOCX](https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx) and [docxtemplater: Can we check-uncheck checkboxes from word document template. #270](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater/issues/270)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use Wingdings font to display symbols (o is a square when font is Wingdings)

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
library(flextable)

doc <- read_docx()

d <- data.frame(checkbox = "o", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  font(fontname = "Wingdings")

doc <- body_add_flextable(doc, d)

print(doc, "test.docx")
```

It seems that real checkboxes are existing in Word but can only be used in some Word version (not mine)!

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. The checkbox in the generated word file cannot be clicked while the box in the word file I sent can be clicked. But I think this is probably the best solution as of now. Thanks again!

Comment: @FenggongWang I updated the answer, you are right, it seems that feature is not working on macOS...